# When does browser automatically clear cache of external JavaScript file?

Tags: caching, browser

I have a JavaScript resource that has the possibility of being edited at any time. Once it is edited I would want it to be propagated to the user's browser relatively quickly (like maybe 15 minutes or so), however, the frequency of this resource being editing is few and far between (maybe 2 a month).

I'd rather the resource to be cached in the browser, since it will be retrieved frequently, but I'd also like the cache to get reset on the browser at a semi-regular interval.

I know I can pass a no-cache header when I request for the resource, but I was wondering when the cache would automatically reset itself on the browser if I did not pass no-cache.

I imagine this would be independent for each browser, but I'm not sure.

I tried to Google this, but most of the hits I found were about clearing the browser's cache... which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You may pass a version string as a get parameter to the URL of your script tag. The parameter won't be evaluated by the static JavaScript file but force the browser to get the new version.

If you do not want to assign the version string every time you edited the source you may compute it based on the file system time stamp or your subversion commit number:

```
<script src="/script.js?time_stamp=1224147832156" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/script.js?svn_version=678" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what we do. Same thing for external CSS files.

Comment: is the javascript for the svn_version=678 cached, or is it reloaded every time (cause theres an get parameter appended)?

Comment: This approach was also used in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: How does one "you may compute it based on the file system time stamp or your subversion commit number"? does SVN do this on commit?

Comment: This isn't bulletproof though, some proxy servers include query parameters as a part of the cache. The best solution is to add the timestamp or the version to the file name. On my site, I generate a 7 digit checksum of the file at build time, so if anything changes in the file a new checksum is generated, the file is renamed, and thus the browser knows to download the updated file.

Answer (score 14):

Put a version on your javascript code like this that is updated when you make a change

```
<script src="/code.js?ver=123" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

They will then always get new version.

Comment: Of course, that assumes the HTML isn't being cached too... ;)

Answer (score 14):

HTTP provides several controls for caching that browsers ignore in different ways.  If you set a reasonable expiration date, most browsers will check to see if they have the current version are appropriate frequencies.

The search term you want to include here (to avoid browser user instructions) is HTTP.

For more see:

- [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)
- [How Web Caches Work](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html) (a little old, but still useful).
- [HTTP/1.1: Caching in HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html)