# Do external JS files get cached the same way images do?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have multiple pages that refer to a single pagehandler script, will the script be called from the browser cache if I navigate from one of these pages to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Here's a workaround: [When does browser automatically clear cache of external JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206783/when-does-browser-automatically-clear-javascript-cache)

Comment: Glad you found this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. External javascript files can be cached in the same way as images.

Your server (apache, iis, etc) will need to be configured to send out the correct http headers to ensure the browser knows if/how to cache the assets.