# ASP.NET - Overriding Javascript and Styleheets cached by browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, browser-cache

I'm working on an asp.net website. I need to make sure my javascript and css updates will be immediately available for returning visitors, without them having to clear their cache to get the latest code. How can I force this when needed, and leave it alone on other occasions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow does this very elegantly IMO. You can see in there source there is a query-string variable passed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=778aaf5a38e2"></script>
```

This will force new load if that changes.

Comment: Using the old "version number in query string" trick really is the way to fly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reliably force a refresh of cached content on the browser you need to change the name / requested URL of the file somehow.

Often this is done by appending a query string to the URL (which is often ignored)

See [When Does Browser Automatically Clear JavaScript Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206783/when-does-browser-automatically-clear-javascript-cache) for a more complete discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to apply no-cache header to those resources, alternatively make the url dynamic somehow.

see - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html