# How do I clear cache before loading page?

Tags: php, javascript, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear browser cache with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php)

I have created a web application which uses so many javascript code. So sometimes it load cached javascript on client pc which is older version from current one. 
So I want to add a code using php or any other method which can clear the cached content before loading the page. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicates - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037249/how-to-clear-browser-cache-with-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206783/when-does-browser-automatically-clear-javascript-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a random $_GET parameter - with a timestamp for example.
Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js?reload=1318923150"></script>
```

Comment: The technique @firian describes above is called "revving". It's quite common in app these days as all of your assets can be concatenated, compressed and cached with a far future expires header.

Answer (score 2):

if you can access the web server, you can set the content expire time to current time, so that the browser will fetch a new version of contents from your web server.

For IIS's steps, view [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313561).

Comment: You can use mod_expires (and .htaccess files) with Apache : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

Answer (score 0):

You could call you javascript files using an additional GET parameter. like:

```
http://example.com/page1/myjs.js?page=page1
```