# External script caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been taught that it is good for page loading speed and user experience to defer loading JavaScript that is non-essential for above-the-fold content.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.src = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js";
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
});
```

But are external JavaScript files that are deferred like this still cached by the user's browser the same way as direct calls to external JavaScript hardcoded into the HTML?

Comment: Yes. [minimum length]

Comment: Put it on a page and refresh?

Comment: Using the browser network tracing tools should show you the source of where such files are loaded from

Comment: It will cahce ss long as the 3rd party is not sending a header that says not to cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. Over sixty browsers - including Blackberry, Epiphany, and PlayStation - happily, and surprisingly, honor caching headers for scripts loaded dynamically.

(See [here](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2012/09/24/async-scripts-cached/)...).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will cache it. So use timestamp or the updated version in the url via query string.

Please see this post for more details

[When does browser automatically clear cache of external JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206783/when-does-browser-automatically-clear-javascript-cache)

Comment: question wasn't `how to prevent cache`. You haven't answered what was asked